# How to get rid of the toxic waste in Capital City Runoff?

Tags: scribblenauts-unlimited

In the level **Capital City Runoff**, the three toxic barrels say:

> There must be a better way to dispose of this waste!

How is this done? I have tried about everything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I personally spawned a shotgun and used it to destroy the barrels and that was it. So basically i think the easiest way is to spawn any type of weapon and use it to destroy the barrels (when you hold the weapon, click on barrel, then click on attack option).

There might be more ways to solve that one, but i think destroying them is the simplest and fastest way.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you. I was looking for a... "cleaner" way to handle the situation, I guess.

Comment: You're welcome. I just shotgun everything that needs to be disposed in any way xD

Comment: Yes, destroying the barrels is the way to do it.  For an ironic solution, try using toxic waste (raw) to destroy the toxic waste (barrel).

Comment: A shotgun is a nice to do it,,, I tried with a "black hole", but even tho the barrels were sucked into it, it didn't work

Comment: Haha! I used a blackhole too.... seemed like the best solution. Black holes don't care.

Comment: I too was looking for a "cleaner" way. I thought the game was trying to make a point.( I guess in a sense it has)

Answer (score 2):

Just click the barrels and "add adjective" type "gone" and they just vanish. Do it for all 3 and you're all set!

Answer (score 2):

I accidently spawned a nuclear cleaner...blew up everything (including the barreld) which did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I used adjective "small", and then placed them in safe.